# как заменить html на странице в определенном блоке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, мне нужно данные которые получаю через ajax там строками вставить в блок .wrap-parameters

я сделал что клонирую блок это будет мой макет, в котором в цикле меняю Value, а теперь как вставить т.е сразу первый блок заменить все т.е wrap_param.html(clone_block); а последующие уже через wrap_param.append(clone_block); ? или есть лучше вариант?
сспасибо!

```js
var clone_block = $('#hidden_param').find('.input_block').clone(true);
var wrap_param = $('.wrap-parameters');
add_param.click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/ajaxRequest/add',
                data:{
                   category:category    
                },
                success:function(data){
                
                    for(var i in data){
                        clone_block.find('.id').val(data[i].id);
                        clone_block.find('.check').val(data[i].print);
                        clone_block.find('.inspection').val(data[i].inspection);
                        clone_block.find('.method').val(data[i].method);
                        clone_block.find('.result').val(data[i].result);
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="wrap-parameters"></div>


<div class="hidden param" data-current_category="{{$dataTypeContent->id}}" id="hidden_param">
    <div class="row input_block">
        <input name="id" type="hidden"  class="field id">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <input name="print" type="checkbox" class="check" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input name="inspection" type="text"  class="field inspection" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input name="method" type="text"  class="field method" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input name="result" type="text"  class="field result" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.wrap-parameters` у вас изначально пустой же... зачем тогда html() ? Можно сразу начать через append и добавлять всё...

Comment: может быть не пустой

Comment: точней наверно как то сразу вставить через html() , т.е все строки которые пришли с ajax только как если мен сначала нужно поменять данные а потом вставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решил зачем заново предыдущие перезагружать, добавить строку в БД, из базы ее вытянуть и через append() вставить в блок .wrap-parameters